# Distance to convex sets in high dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose you have a compact convex polytope $S \subset {\bf R}^n$.

Is it possible that for a linear subspace $V \subset {\bf R}^n$

the quantity $\inf_{x \in V \setminus S} {d(x, S) \over d(x, S \cap V)}$ is zero (i.e. the ratio of distance from $x$ to $S \cap V$ and distance to $S$ can be arbitrarily small where $x$ ranges over points in $V$)

here $d$ is the least Euclidean distance distance

Comment: Let $n=2, S=[0,1] \times \{0\}$ and $V$ be the $y$ axis.Then $d_S((1,t)) = |t|, d_{S \cap V}((1,t)) = \sqrt{1+t^2}$ hence the ratio can be made as small as you want.

Comment: x needs to be in $V$